# Force 'Shared User Defaults Controller' to save to disk immediately?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, preferences

I have a preferences pane that uses the Shared User Defaults Controller, which reading and saving preferences a piece of cake.   It seems though that when changes are made to the fields, they aren't immediately saved to the plist fie.  This creates a problem when my application needs to re-read the file immediately after the change has been made and the plist still hasn't been updated.

How can I force the preferences pane to update the preferences file immediately?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This will automatically save any change you do right away to disk:

```
NSUserDefaultsController *controller = [NSUserDefaultsController sharedUserDefaultsController];
[controller setAppliesImmediately:YES];
```

If you need this only in specific cases, you can also use and save some of the expensive I/O (you really should try to let the cache mechanism cache as much as possible instead of writing everything right away to disk):

```
NSUserDefaultsController *controller = [NSUserDefaultsController sharedUserDefaultsController];
[controller save:self];
```

Also, are you sure that you are trying to solve the right problem? You can always get the up to date version of the user defaults by querying `NSUserDefaults` where you don't need to care about wether the current version is cached in RAM or already written to disk.

Comment: The problem I'm trying to solve is that another object is being called, and that object can't read those values directly.  As a result, he has to pull them from disk.  Pulling it from NSUserDefaults is probably a better way than reading from disk.

Comment: @Adam Yup, I would highly encourage you to use `NSUserDefaults` in this case!

Answer (score 0):

Per the docs:

```
[userDefaults save:self];
```

or

```
[userDefaults setAppliesImmediately:YES];
```